# SPARK aggregate all columns base on one column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, bigdata, aggregate

For simplicity let's assume that I have the following daraframe:

```
col X col Y col Z
A     1     5
A     2     10
A     3     10
B     5     15
```

I want to Groupby column X and aggregate by taking min value of Z however I want the Y value to be the adjcent value of min value Z

```
df.groupBy("X").agg(min("Z"), take_y_according_to_min_z("Y")
```

Desired output:

```
col X col Y col Z
A     1     5
B     5     15
```

Note: If there are more than two `min("Z")` values I don't care which of the rows we take.

I tried to find something online which is clean and SPARKy. It's really clear to me how I can do it in MapReduce but I can't find a way on SPARK.

I'm working on SPARK 1.6

Comment: you can combine y and z in struct and find the min and finally separate them again

Comment: Yes this was my first approach, as I said I wanted a more clean approach if there is one. Seems like a big effort for simple task

Comment: thats not a big effort ;) thats simple effort

Comment: @RameshMaharjan to struct groupby aggregate and than explode?

Comment: nope :) you don't need explode. just use wild card character .* to separate the struct column I am just trying to find a duplicate as I have seen somebody answer the same

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan Can you post it as an answer to the question I think I missing something. Assuming that there is more than one column Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(col("Col X"), struct("Col Z", "Col Y").as("struct"))
  .groupBy("Col X").agg(min(col("struct")).as("min"))
    .select(col("Col X"), col("min.*"))
```

and you shall get what you desire

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|Col X|Col Y|Col Z|
+-----+-----+-----+
|B    |5    |15   |
|A    |1    |5    |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: `struct("Col Y", "Col Z")` should be `struct("Col Z", "Col Y")` as minimum has to be from `Col Z`

Comment: agg(min(col("struct")).as("min")) How this know that I want the min value of col Z and not Y?

Comment: @vindev So it takes the minimum value from the first cell in the struct?

Comment: thank you @vindev I have corrected

Comment: Yes @RefiPeretz you got it right it takes all elements in struct columns but the first element is sorted the first so Z should come first

Answer (score 1):

You can use `struct` as with the column `Y` and `Z` as

```
df.groupBy("X").agg(min(struct("Z", "Y")).as("min"))
    .select("X", "min.*")
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+
|X  |Z  |Y  |
+---+---+---+
|B  |15 |5  |
|A  |5  |1  |
+---+---+---+
```

Hope this helps1